# how to subset a netcdf file using latlong details and rewrite to a new nc file?

Tags: python, netcdf4

I am trying to subset a netcdf file using latlong. I have created the file but it is not opening by *ncdump*

I tried like this

```
from netCDF4 import *
from numpy import *
import time

#Read and subset
nc_file = Dataset('D:\\R_Workspace\\19971207.nc','r')

latbound = [16,20]
longbound = [73,77]

lats = nc_file.variables['Latitude'][:]
lons = nc_file.variables['Longitude'][:]

lat_lb = argmin(abs(lats-latbound[0]))
lat_ub = argmin(abs(lats-latbound[1]))

lon_lb = argmin(abs(lons-longbound[0]))
lon_ub = argmin(abs(lons-longbound[1]))

sm_sub = nc_file.variables['soil_moisture_x'][lon_lb:lon_ub,lat_ub:lat_lb]
lat_sub = nc_file.variables['Latitude'][lat_ub:lat_lb]
lon_sub = nc_file.variables['Longitude'][lon_lb:lon_ub]
nc_file.close()

#write to new file
my_file = Dataset('D:\\R_Workspace\\subset\\19971207.nc','w', format = 'NETCDF4')

my_file.discription = 'SM-TRMM-night_UB-subset'
my_file.history = 'Created on: ' +time.ctime(time.time())

#Dimensions
ldim = lat_lb-lat_ub # getting the no of element
lndim = lon_ub-lon_lb

lon = my_file.createDimension('lon',lndim)
lat = my_file.createDimension('lat',ldim)

#Variables
latitude = my_file.createVariable('Latitude',float32,('lat',))
latitude.units = 'Degree_north'
longitude = my_file.createVariable('Longitude',float32,('lon',))
longitude.units = 'Degree_east'

sm = my_file.createVariable('SM',float32,('lon','lat'),fill_value = -9999.0)
sm.units = 'percent'

#Load values to the variables
latitude[:] = lat_sub
longitude[:] = lon_sub
sm[:] = sm_sub
my_file.close()
```

the code is not giving any error but created nc file is not proper and ncdump is also failed to open it. Pls help me to sort out this problem. Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try copying over the global attributes from `ncfile` to `myfile`

```
 g_attdict = ncfile.__dict__
```

...

```
myfile.setncatts(g_attdict)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sm_sub` is 2D:

```
sm_sub = nc_file.variables['soil_moisture_x'][lon_lb:lon_ub,lat_ub:lat_lb]
```

You're correctly declaring the output variable `sm` as a 2D variable (lat x lon) here:

```
sm = my_file.createVariable('SM',float32,('lon','lat'),fill_value = -9999.0)
```

but only writing out 1-dimension:

```
sm[:] = sm_sub
```

So that line needs to change to:

```
sm[:,:] = sm_sub[:,:]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done on Unix systems in a few lines using my nctoolkit (https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
ds = nc.open_data("infile.nc")

latbound = [16,20]
longbound = [73,77]

ds.crop(lon = longbound, lat = latbound)
ds.to_nc("outfile.nc")
```

Comment: looks nice. Is there a simple reason why your `crop` is faster than xarray ?  Is there a fast `.values` or the like ? (I personally don't care for huge old packages, and `cdo` looks huge ... will try `pip install cdo` on macos 10.15) Thanks

Comment: I've never benchmarked this, and this is probably something that is very dependent on the type of grid you are looking at, so speed ups might vary. Right now there is no .values method, but that might feature soon